# If a bird fly to height of $h$ ,What's the area that it can see?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Suppose a bird fly to height $h$ from earth . The bird can see area under by it's eyes ,name as $S$ ,What's $max \{S\}$ ?
Is it possible to solve  ?

my first trial was to assume a cone by $height =h$ and $S=\pi R^2$ as area like the figure I attached with.[image]

Is $S$ a constant for special amount of $h$ ?
can we calculate $max \{S\}$ or $S$?(or something is missed  ?)

Thanks for any hint ,in advance.

Comment: Consider the 3 points of the bird, the center of the earth, and the furthest point away that the bird can see.  This forms a right triangle.

Comment: I am not sure how high that bird can fly, but the fact that Earth is spherical makes this problem quite an interesting one. If you assume the Earth to be locally flat, the problem might be easier. +1

Comment: There is a third parameter (apart from $h$ and $R$): the angle of vision of the bird. I think that is also needed for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I became interested in this problem and the word "bird" caught my attention.

We have a geometric approach given by John Bentin.

But birds' eyes have a lateral, a frontal and a blind areas of vision in the horizontal plane.

I couldn`t find anything in the vertical plane.

See http://people.eku.edu/ritchisong/birdbrain2.html

Besides there are three kinds of visual fields

http://estebanfj.bio.purdue.edu/birdvision/visualfields.html

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view

we can find two sketches showing the horizontal and the vertical fields of view.

Also found that there is a visual-field projections on orthographically viewed spheres (that I am trying to understand)

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313038494_White-headed_Vulture_Trigonoceps_occipitalis_shows_visual_field_characteristics_of_hunting_raptors

and

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232225655_Extreme_binocular_vision_and_a_straight_bill_facilitate_tool_use_in_New_Caledonian_crows

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there is no limitation on the angle of vision of the bird.

The only known values I am assuming is the half apex angle $\theta$.

By property of tangent, the half angle subtended at the center will be $90-\theta$.

By using the solid angle formula,

$$
A=\phi r^2=2\pi(1-\cos{(90-\theta}) = 2\pi (1-\sin{\theta})
$$

Comment: Where is $h$  in final formula  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Edited Accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Assume the earth to be a sphere of radius $r$ with centre $O$. Let the bird be at a point $B$, with a point $H$ on the horizon as seen by the bird. Then $OH=r$, $OB=r+h$, $HB\perp HO$, and $$\sin\angle OBH=\frac r{r+h}.$$The area of the spherical cap seen by the bird is$$2\pi r^2(1-\cos\angle BOH)=2\pi r^2(1-\sin\angle OBH)$$$$\qquad=2\pi\frac{r^2h}{r+h}.$$